# Spring boot batch with HibernateCursorItemReader not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-batch

Any idea why could I be getting below error with following code?

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemReader<OrderDetail> reader(@Value("#{jobParameters['orderDate']}") final String orderDate)
        throws UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, Exception {
    LOGGER.info("START of reader() with args: ", orderDate);

    final Date beginDate = new Date();
    final Date endDate = new Date();
    final Map<String, Object> parameterValues = new HashMap<>();
    parameterValues.put("beginDate", beginDate);
    parameterValues.put("endDate", endDate);

    final HibernateCursorItemReader<OrderDetail> itemReader = new HibernateCursorItemReader<>();
    itemReader.setQueryString("select dtl from OrderDetail dtl join OrderSummary sumy on dtl.orderId = sumy.id where orderDate between
        :beginDate and :endDate order by id desc");
    itemReader.setParameterValues(parameterValues);
    itemReader.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    itemReader.setUseStatelessSession(true);
    itemReader.afterPropertiesSet();

    LOGGER.info("END of reader()");

    return itemReader;
}
```

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null  at
>   org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateCursorItemReader.doRead(HibernateCursorItemReader.java:155)
>
> at
>   org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:88)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy245.read(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:157)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:116)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:110)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:69)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:272)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy244.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return `HibernateCursorItemReader` instead of `ItemReader`  StepScope need specific implementation type .

Comment: Thanks for your response Niraj. I am actually returning HibernateCursorItemReader, see below code:

final HibernateCursorItemReader<OrderDetail> itemReader = new HibernateCursorItemReader<>();

Comment: change return type of  reader method signature  to HibernateCursorItemReader

Comment: I have actually changed return type on the method signature to HibernateCursorItemReader instead of ItemReader and I see some progress. However, I get this another error:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.StatelessSession.createQuery(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/hibernate/Query;

Comment: if the above maintained issue is fix then accept the answer by clicking  on the check mark beside the answer.. And post new question with  Exception Details and Configuration details. please format code correctly it's very difficult to understand